# Animation for activity(intent)

Tags: java, android

my promblem is : i cant use animition for intent becuse this calss extend recyclerView adapter i know overridePendingTransition();but its dont work for tis class

It does not know =>             overridePendingTransition(R.layout.one,R.layout.two);

public class ListAdapterw extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
List<cardViewhomeinfo> sliders;
ImageLoader imageLoader=ImageLoader.getInstance();

public ListAdapterw(List<cardViewhomeinfo> sliders) {
    this.sliders = sliders;
}

@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycleview_home,parent,false);
    return new Holder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
    holder.title.setText(sliders.get(position).getTitle());
   holder.id=sliders.get(position).getId();
    imageLoader.displayImage("http://wwwww"+sliders.get(position).getPicture(),holder.pic);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sliders.size();
}

public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

 public   TextView title;
   public ImageView pic;
   public String id="";
    CardView cardView;

    public Holder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.TitleCardView_home);
        pic=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageCardView_home);
        cardView= (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(),subCat.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("id",id);
            overridePendingTransition(R.layout.one,R.layout.two);
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

}
and my activtity

public class Home extends Fragment {

```
View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    JSON();

    return view;
}

private void JSON() {

    final RecyclerView recyclerView1 = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_home);

    StringRequest request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {

            try {

                List<cardViewhomeinfo> sliders = new ArrayList<>();

                JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(s);

                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                cardViewhomeinfo slider = new cardViewhomeinfo();

                slider.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                slider.setPicture(jsonObject.getString("pic"));
                slider.setId(jsonObject.getString("id"));

                    sliders.add(slider);

            }

                ListAdapterw adapter = new ListAdapterw(sliders);
                recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
                recyclerView1.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            dialog();
        }
    });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).add(request);
}

private void dialog() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"No INTENT",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("Home");
}
```

}
and subActivty

public class subCat extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_cat);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String idCat = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),idCat,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

Comment: Intent is for starting an activity. Adapter is for defining data for a view. Can you please elaborate what effect do you want to apply, to either the elements of recycler view or between activities ?

Comment: When I go from one page to another,i need animationActivty i know its dont work overridePendingTransition(R.layout.one,R.layout.two); when user click on my recycleView must go to other activty (subCat) with anmition

Comment: Do you want a pending transition from activity you're going to when you click on cardView of recycler view or do you want the recyclerView activity to have transition when loaded? Which activity it is. Post that activity's code here.

Comment: i want a pending transition from activity you're going to when you click on cardView of recycler view

Comment: Post that activity's code here please.

Comment: i eidt my post plz check it ty

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `overridePendingTransition(R.layout.one,R.layout.two);` code into the onCreate of the activity that you're going to when you click on cardView.

It should be something like this in your onCreate method of the activity:

```
public class subCat extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_cat);

 overridePendingTransition(R.layout.one,R.layout.two); //Put it here.

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
Intent intent = getIntent();
final String idCat = intent.getStringExtra("id");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),idCat,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Remove `overridePendingTransition(R.layout.one,R.layout.two);` this from the adapter class of your recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand,

`overridePendingTransition(R.layout.one,R.layout.two);`
it should be called

after `finish();`
or
after `startActivity();`